# A fast look up value in vectors MATLAB code comparion

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, mex

I am using MATLAB to look up the value in two vectors `OCT_EXP`, `OCT_LOG`, from two input values `u,v` and output is `val` as condition

```
if (( u == 0 )||( v == 0 ))
    val = 0;
else
    val = OCT_EXP( OCT_LOG(u) + OCT_LOG(v) + 1);
```

I tried to use three ways: **normal way (no_vectorized way), vectorized way, and mex way**. I expected that mex way will be the best way, then vectorized way. However, when I measure time consumption, the first way (no vectorized way) is best, the vectorized way is worst way. What is happen in my code? Thank all

I want to consider the speed up of the function because it will be called many time: 300.000 times

The first way:

```
function val = gfmult_no_vec( u, v )

OCT_EXP = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,...
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 157,...
   39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159, 35,...
   70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111, 222,...
   161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30, 60,...
   120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223, 163,...
   91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26, 52,...
   104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147, 59,...
   118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,...
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,...
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,...
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,...
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,...
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,...
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,...
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,...
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,...
   142, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,...
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192,...
   157, 39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159,...
   35, 70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111,...
   222, 161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30,...
   60, 120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223,...
   163, 91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26,...
   52, 104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147,...
   59, 118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,...
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,...
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,...
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,...
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,...
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,...
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,...
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,...
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,...
   142 ];

OCT_LOG = [ 0, 1, 25, 2, 50, 26, 198, 3, 223, 51, 238, 27, 104, 199, 75, 4,...
   100, 224, 14, 52, 141, 239, 129, 28, 193, 105, 248, 200, 8, 76, 113, 5,...
   138, 101, 47, 225, 36, 15, 33, 53, 147, 142, 218, 240, 18, 130, 69,...
   29, 181, 194, 125, 106, 39, 249, 185, 201, 154, 9, 120, 77, 228, 114,... end

   166, 6, 191, 139, 98, 102, 221, 48, 253, 226, 152, 37, 179, 16, 145,...
   34, 136, 54, 208, 148, 206, 143, 150, 219, 189, 241, 210, 19, 92,...
   131, 56, 70, 64, 30, 66, 182, 163, 195, 72, 126, 110, 107, 58, 40,...
   84, 250, 133, 186, 61, 202, 94, 155, 159, 10, 21, 121, 43, 78, 212,...
   229, 172, 115, 243, 167, 87, 7, 112, 192, 247, 140, 128, 99, 13, 103,...
   74, 222, 237, 49, 197, 254, 24, 227, 165, 153, 119, 38, 184, 180,...
   124, 17, 68, 146, 217, 35, 32, 137, 46, 55, 63, 209, 91, 149, 188,...
   207, 205, 144, 135, 151, 178, 220, 252, 190, 97, 242, 86, 211, 171,...
   20, 42, 93, 158, 132, 60, 57, 83, 71, 109, 65, 162, 31, 45, 67, 216,...
   183, 123, 164, 118, 196, 23, 73, 236, 127, 12, 111, 246, 108, 161,...
   59, 82, 41, 157, 85, 170, 251, 96, 134, 177, 187, 204, 62, 90, 203,...
   89, 95, 176, 156, 169, 160, 81, 11, 245, 22, 235, 122, 117, 44, 215,...
   79, 174, 213, 233, 230, 231, 173, 232, 116, 214, 244, 234, 168, 80,...
   88, 175 ];

    if (( u == 0 )||( v == 0 ))
        val = 0;
    else
        val = OCT_EXP( OCT_LOG(u) + OCT_LOG(v) + 1);
```

The second way: Vectorized way

```
function val = gfmult_vec( u, v )

OCT_EXP = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,...
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 157,...
   39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159, 35,...
   70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111, 222,...
   161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30, 60,...
   120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223, 163,...
   91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26, 52,...
   104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147, 59,...
   118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,...
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,...
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,...
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,...
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,...
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,...
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,...
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,...
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,...
   142, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,...
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192,...
   157, 39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159,...
   35, 70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111,...
   222, 161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30,...
   60, 120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223,...
   163, 91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26,...
   52, 104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147,...
   59, 118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,...
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,...
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,...
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,...
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,...
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,...
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,...
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,...
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,...
   142 ];

OCT_LOG = [ 0, 1, 25, 2, 50, 26, 198, 3, 223, 51, 238, 27, 104, 199, 75, 4,...
   100, 224, 14, 52, 141, 239, 129, 28, 193, 105, 248, 200, 8, 76, 113, 5,...
   138, 101, 47, 225, 36, 15, 33, 53, 147, 142, 218, 240, 18, 130, 69,...
   29, 181, 194, 125, 106, 39, 249, 185, 201, 154, 9, 120, 77, 228, 114,... 
   166, 6, 191, 139, 98, 102, 221, 48, 253, 226, 152, 37, 179, 16, 145,...
   34, 136, 54, 208, 148, 206, 143, 150, 219, 189, 241, 210, 19, 92,...
   131, 56, 70, 64, 30, 66, 182, 163, 195, 72, 126, 110, 107, 58, 40,...
   84, 250, 133, 186, 61, 202, 94, 155, 159, 10, 21, 121, 43, 78, 212,...
   229, 172, 115, 243, 167, 87, 7, 112, 192, 247, 140, 128, 99, 13, 103,...
   74, 222, 237, 49, 197, 254, 24, 227, 165, 153, 119, 38, 184, 180,...
   124, 17, 68, 146, 217, 35, 32, 137, 46, 55, 63, 209, 91, 149, 188,...
   207, 205, 144, 135, 151, 178, 220, 252, 190, 97, 242, 86, 211, 171,...
   20, 42, 93, 158, 132, 60, 57, 83, 71, 109, 65, 162, 31, 45, 67, 216,...
   183, 123, 164, 118, 196, 23, 73, 236, 127, 12, 111, 246, 108, 161,...
   59, 82, 41, 157, 85, 170, 251, 96, 134, 177, 187, 204, 62, 90, 203,...
   89, 95, 176, 156, 169, 160, 81, 11, 245, 22, 235, 122, 117, 44, 215,...
   79, 174, 213, 233, 230, 231, 173, 232, 116, 214, 244, 234, 168, 80,...
   88, 175 ];

    uv0 =  (~(( u == 0 )|( v == 0 )));
    val = zeros(size(u));
    val(uv0) = OCT_EXP( OCT_LOG(u(uv0)) + OCT_LOG(v(uv0)) + 1);
end
```

The last way: mex code

```
#include "mex.h"
double look_up(double u, double v)
{
   double OCT_EXP [510] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 157,
   39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159, 35,
   70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111, 222,
   161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30, 60,
   120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223, 163,
   91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26, 52,
   104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147, 59,
   118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,
   142, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192,
   157, 39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159,
   35, 70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111,
   222, 161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30,
   60, 120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223,
   163, 91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26,
   52, 104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147,
   59, 118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,
   142 };

   double OCT_LOG[255] = { 0, 1, 25, 2, 50, 26, 198, 3, 223, 51, 238, 27, 104, 199, 75, 4,
   100, 224, 14, 52, 141, 239, 129, 28, 193, 105, 248, 200, 8, 76, 113, 5,
   138, 101, 47, 225, 36, 15, 33, 53, 147, 142, 218, 240, 18, 130, 69,
   29, 181, 194, 125, 106, 39, 249, 185, 201, 154, 9, 120, 77, 228, 114, 
   166, 6, 191, 139, 98, 102, 221, 48, 253, 226, 152, 37, 179, 16, 145,
   34, 136, 54, 208, 148, 206, 143, 150, 219, 189, 241, 210, 19, 92,
   131, 56, 70, 64, 30, 66, 182, 163, 195, 72, 126, 110, 107, 58, 40,
   84, 250, 133, 186, 61, 202, 94, 155, 159, 10, 21, 121, 43, 78, 212,
   229, 172, 115, 243, 167, 87, 7, 112, 192, 247, 140, 128, 99, 13, 103,
   74, 222, 237, 49, 197, 254, 24, 227, 165, 153, 119, 38, 184, 180,
   124, 17, 68, 146, 217, 35, 32, 137, 46, 55, 63, 209, 91, 149, 188,
   207, 205, 144, 135, 151, 178, 220, 252, 190, 97, 242, 86, 211, 171,
   20, 42, 93, 158, 132, 60, 57, 83, 71, 109, 65, 162, 31, 45, 67, 216,
   183, 123, 164, 118, 196, 23, 73, 236, 127, 12, 111, 246, 108, 161,
   59, 82, 41, 157, 85, 170, 251, 96, 134, 177, 187, 204, 62, 90, 203,
   89, 95, 176, 156, 169, 160, 81, 11, 245, 22, 235, 122, 117, 44, 215,
   79, 174, 213, 233, 230, 231, 173, 232, 116, 214, 244, 234, 168, 80,
   88, 175 };

    if (( u == 0 )||( v == 0 ))
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int index=OCT_LOG[int(u-1)] + OCT_LOG[int(v-1)] + 1;
        return OCT_EXP [index-1];
    }

}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *u, *v, *uv;
    int mrows, ncols;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1, mxREAL);
    /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
     u = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);    
     v = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
     uv = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    *uv = look_up(*u, *v);
}
```

The measurement code

```
function main
    function test1()
        for i=1:200
            for j=1:200
                gfmult_no_vec(i,j);
            end
        end
    end

    function test2()
        for i=1:200
            for j=1:200
                gfmult_vec(i,j);
            end
        end
    end

    function test3()
        for i=1:200
            for j=1:200
                gfmult_mex(i,j);
            end
        end
    end
f1=@()test1();
t1=timeit(f1)

f2=@()test2();
t2=timeit(f2)

f3=@()test3();
t3=timeit(f3)
end
```

**Report time**:
**t1 =  0.1934,
t2 =  1.1739,
t3 =   0.3584**

Comment: You shouldn't expect mex to be the best, a full vectorized way will always be faster. However, in your code non of the methods is fully vectorized, because you use loops in all of them.

Comment: None of these are vectorized. The function is called using 2 scalars as argument which means `u` and `v` would be scalar. The consequence is just that you do a lot of unnecessary work in the second equation.

Comment: Also, `u` and `v` are never zeros (goes from `1:200`) so why are you testing for that?

Comment: Thank all. How could I improve my code?

Comment: I just use for to testing because the function will be called many time. We can control zero by rand number but it does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution takes **0.0006** second in my computer (and it is vectorized):

```
u = randi(5,200,1)-1; % some arbitrary data including zeros
v = randi(5,200,1)-1; % some arbitrary data including zeros
[U,V] = ndgrid(u(u~=0),v(v~=0)); % make all possible combinations of u and v
val = zeros(length(u),length(v)); % initialize the output size, in case the last value in u or v is zero.
f = @(u,v) OCT_EXP(OCT_LOG(u)+OCT_LOG(v)+1);
val((u~=0),(v~=0)) = f(U,V);
```

Now `val(u,v) = OCT_EXP(OCT_LOG(u)+OCT_LOG(v)+1)` if `u` and `v` are both not zeros, otherwise `val(u,v) = 0`.

---

If you want `gfmult` to have a scalar input, then your first method seems to be the fastest way. However, I would define `OCT_EXP` and `OCT_LOG` outside the function and pass them to it, instead of assigning this values over and over:

```
function val = gfmult(OCT_EXP,OCT_LOG,u,v)
if (u==0)||(v==0)
    val = 0;
else
    val = OCT_EXP(OCT_LOG(u)+OCT_LOG(v)+1);
end
end
```

in my computer it reduces running time from **0.21444** (with your version) to **0.158** second for 100K iteration, which is not such a big improvement (0.05644 second), but if you have millions of those, it may be significant.

Comment: Thank EBH, Actually, I only want to improve code in the` gfmult` function for two scale value `u,v`. I use two for loop to test time. Your code look make the input of `gfmult` function are vectorized.

Comment: I not sure I get your point, if both `u` and `v` are scalars, then there is nothing to vectorize... however, if you are about to run this input on many `u`'s and `v`'s, then why treating them as scalars?

Comment: Sorry, I may be wrong when said about vectorized word. Let just consider function `gfmult` only. I will call the function many time (~100000 times), so I express it by using two loops. If we can improve inside the function a little in an iteration, we achieve a so much improvement after 100000 iterations. I just only want to improve inside the function `gfmult` because it called in various position, I cannot change all to vectorized way for these position, Hence, I want to maintain the input and output of the function, and improve inside it. Is it possible.

Comment: @user3051460 I think you're already hitting the bottom, but see my edit for a last tiny squeeze.

Comment: Yes, I think so, Your solution is good when we use OCT_EXP and OCT_LOG as local variable. I tried to search it before by using `persistent` before these vectors. But it does not work in my MATLAB. Do you think that can we use `persistent`  inside the function `gfmult`

Comment: Using `persistent OCT_EXP OCT_LOG` makes this function x9 slower than just passing `OCT_EXP` and `OCT_LOG`. The fastest solution will be to pass them to wherever they needed, and if you want to make things more tidy you can combine them in a struct (like: `OCT.EXP = OCT_EXP; OCT.LOG = OCT_LOG`) so you'll only have to pass `OCT`